# The Type does not Exist in the namespace. Are you missing an Assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, class, namespaces, .net-2.0

I have 2 **C#** projects first one name is "Advocar" and the second one is "Import".

There is a class in Advocar project which we need to access to that from Import project. So in Import project I added reference to Advocar.

The problem is from Import project I recognizes all the Advocar classes except the new class that I just created in the Advocar. and when I build it, it say "The Type or namespace does not exist in the Advocar.Data.Inventory namespace. Are you missing an assembly?", but the class is exist in that namespace.

I build Advocar project and re-add the assembly to the Import project and it did not help. Both project are in **.NET 2.0.**

- Any Idea please?

Comment: is the class marked public?

Answer (score 1):

Check the access level of new class added into the namespace.

Comment: Its back again! I checked the permission and they are all fine. I dont know whats going on?!

Comment: In Visual Studio, select "Clean Solution" option and then rebuild the solution again. Hope you have reference to the project instead of ref. to DLL file.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found the solution although I dont know what would cause that.
since 40% of all the classes that I have are the same code, so to create a new class I just copied and pasted one of the existing class and made changes on that one. 
So to solve my issue, I deleted the new classes and I just Add New Item and create a blank class and past the code that I needed to the new class and it fixed that.
Its look like some kind of caching issue that although you rename a class and so on, but it still has some record from past.

Comment: You might want to check the Build Action for those classes. I copied a bunch of classes from one project to another, and I would get the message about the type not existing. After reading your answer, I checked the Build Action and it was set to "Content". Changing it to "Compile" fixed the problem immediately.